# FuncOne() -and FuncTwo() not working

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-5.0

This is my code:

```
if (FuncOne($valOne) -and FuncTwo($valTwo)) {
    ...
}
```

When both of those functions evaluate to `$false`, the code within the if statement still executes. Why is that? This also does not work as expected:

```
if (FuncOne($valOne) -eq $true -and FuncTwo($valTwo) -eq $true) {
    ...
}
```

When written this way, it works as expected.

```
$a = FuncOne($valOne)
$b = FuncTwo($valTwo)

if($a -and $b) {
    ...
}
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a syntax issue.

The correct syntax for invoking functions in PowerShell is not:

```
functionName($arg1[,$arg2,$arg3])
```

but rather:

```
functionName [-parameterName1] $arg1 [[-parameterName2] $arg2]
```

Now, let's apply this to your `if()` sample expression:

```
FuncOne $valOne -and FuncTwo $valTwo
```

You'll notice that explicit parameter names (`-ParameterName`) and operators (`-and`) are completely indistinguishable - there's no way for the parser to tell whether `-and` is supposed to be interpreted as a parameter name or an operator. Additionally, the string literal `FuncTwo` can just as well be interpreted as a parameter argument, which is exactly what happens.

In order for the parser to *know* that you intend it to treat the expression as two separate expressions, force evaluation order with `()`:

```
if ((FuncOne $valOne) -and (FuncTwo $valTwo)) {
    # They both returns a truthy value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You actualy need to place the function in parenthese in order to *invoke* it:

```
if ((FuncOne($valOne)) -and (FuncTwo($valTwo))) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So powershell is thinking FuncOne is defined as something, therefore, coerce to $true?

Comment: No, it thinks `-and` is a parameter name and `FuncTwo` is an argument

Comment: Mathias is right and his answer explains the problem.

Comment: Yes, the parenthesis should be around the function *and* include the arguments. You should not use parenthesis around the argument(s): `if ((FuncOne $valOne) -and (FuncTwo $valTwo)) {...`